# select an xml type column in select query with group by SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, xml, group-by

I am writing a select query in which I am fetching several columns (by joining 3-4 tables).
I use group by clause to group my results.

Query -

```
    select ci.Candidate_Id, ci.FirstName, ci.DetailXML
from Candidate_Instance ci 
where ci.Candidate_Instance_Id=2
group by 
ci.Candidate_Id, ci.FirstName, ci.DetailXML
```

One of the tables have a column which is of XML data type. When I add the column in the select list, I get this error -

**Column 'table.myXML' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.**

and when I add the column in the group by clause, I get this error -

**The XML data type cannot be compared or sorted, except when using the IS NULL operator.**

I am quite confused as to how to come out of this.
I want to get the XML data from the column.

Thanks

Comment: Can you give us the actual query and table structures so we can see why you are using `GROUP BY` at all? You aren't using any aggregates there. Also can a `CandidateId` have multiple different `DetailXML` rows?

Comment: Martin, my original query is quite long and explaining my table structure would be quite inconvenient. I understand your point, but I cant discuss my DB structure over here. I just want a tip/trick to get things moving.

Comment: If candidate_id is a primary key within candidate_instance this is simple: You can use a cte and join the cte to that table selecting the XML. This will be much faster than the acepted answer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You cannot group by XML or TEXT columns, you would first need to convert to varchar(max)

```
select ci.Candidate_Id, ci.FirstName, convert(xml,convert(varchar(max),ci.DetailXML)) DetailXML
from Candidate_Instance ci 
where ci.Candidate_Instance_Id=2
group by 
ci.Candidate_Id, ci.FirstName, convert(varchar(max),ci.DetailXML)
```

On the first line, it is converted to varchar(max) to match the GROUP BY clause, and later it is re-cast back to XML.

Comment: @saarthak - Be interesting to know whether it is actually casting it to `varchar(max)` and then sorting these huge strings or whether it avoids this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure why you are using `group by` here based on the information in your question but anyway this whould work as it seems you are only including it in the `group by` in order to be able to `select` it.

```
;with cte as
(
    select ci.Candidate_Id, 
           ci.FirstName, 
           ci.DetailXML, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION by ci.Candidate_Id, ci.FirstName ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS RN
    from Candidate_Instance ci  
    where ci.Candidate_Instance_Id=2 
)
SELECT Candidate_Id, FirstName, DetailXML
FROM cte
WHERE RN=1
```

Comment: Hi Martin, Thanks for replying. I could have managed like this but the point is that I have a query which is having group by and I need to add a XML type column in the select list. In your answer, can you tell me how would you use group by here?

Comment: Not until I understand the purpose of the `GROUP BY`. If you are using it to remove duplicates brought in by a `JOIN` I would probably write the query in entirely another way. (e.g. using `WHERE EXISTS` rather than a `JOIN`)

Answer (score 1):

If you have any column(s) with unique data in your table you can use a CTE, what would be a fast solution if there is an index on that column(s):

```
with cte as 
(
select 
    ci.Candidate_Id, 
    ci.FirstName
from Candidate_Instance ci 
where ci.Candidate_Instance_Id=2
group by 
     ci.Candidate_Id, 
     ci.FirstName
)
select 
    a.*,
    b.DetailXML
from cte a
inner join Candidate_Instance b
on a.Candidate_Id = b.Candidate_Id -- <--this must be unique within Candidate_Instance
```