# SQL Server aggregation with several joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, aggregation

I'm trying to join data from 3 tables in SQL Servre and display in result:

- Alias of an entity
- if the entity is virtual
- the last date (if known)
- the value (if known)

I tried this :

```
select 
    sr.alias, c.virtual, max(d.date) date
from 
    App_references sr 
join 
    Sensor c on (c.id_capteur = sr.id_capteur) 
left join 
    Sensor_data d on (c.id_capteur = d.id_capteur)
group by 
    d.id_capteur, sr.alias, c.virtual
order by 
    sr.alias
```

Here is the database scheme:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[App_reference]
(
    [id_ref] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [alias] [varchar](60) NOT NULL,
    [id_capteur] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_App_reference] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id_ref] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Sensor]
(
    [id_capteur] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [virtual] [tinyint] NULL,
    [unite] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [id_type] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Sensor] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id_capteur] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Sensor_data]
(
    [id_entry] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [id_capteur] [int] NOT NULL,
    [value] [xml] NOT NULL,
    [date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Sensor_data] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id_entry] ASC,
    [id_capteur] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

Supposing each columns like "id_%" are linked by foreign key.

The request on top pass well, I got value :

```
alias               virtual date
Place 1 (Physique)  0       2017-04-27 14:58:42.423
Place 2             1       NULL
Place 3             1       NULL
```

But I tried to select the value too by doing this :

```
select 
    sr.alias, c.virtual, max(d.date) date, d.value
from 
    Citopia_test.dbo.Smartparking_reference sr 
join 
    Citopia_test.dbo.Sensor c on (c.id_capteur = sr.id_capteur) 
left join 
    Citopia_test.dbo.Sensor_data d on (c.id_capteur = d.id_capteur)
group by 
    d.id_capteur, sr.alias, c.virtual
order by 
    sr.alias
```

And I got this error :

> Column 'Sensor_data.value' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

So I tried several things like adding column in the group by but nothing changes.

Comment: Think it is because the Sensor_data.value is XML. You cannot group by XML. Cast it to an NVARCHAR(MAX) and try again, adding it to the group by.

Comment: can you add some sample data please

Comment: Agree with @Leonidas199x. See accepted answer here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222212/select-an-xml-type-column-in-select-query-with-group-by-sql-server-2008

Comment: Yes, that work. Actually, i use XML before i don't really know how to store data that could be various, like bool or integer or float etc... So i tried with xml as i read it on another post. Do you think nvarchar is better to use ?

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the columns you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: Do you want to do something with that value in the database or only display it? If it's just for display, then nvarchar seems appropriate.

Comment: Yet, this table is used as a log, so each time i get data from a sensor, this will store a new line on the table. So yes, it's just to display it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You probably want the value from the record with max date. Use `ROW_NUMBER` to get those records.

```
select alias, virtual, date, value
from
(
  select 
    sr.alias, c.virtual, d.date, d.value,
    row_number() over (partition by sr.alias order by d.date desc) as rn
  from Citopia_test.dbo.Smartparking_reference sr 
  join Citopia_test.dbo.Sensor c on (c.id_capteur = sr.id_capteur) 
  left join Citopia_test.dbo.Sensor_data d on (c.id_capteur = d.id_capteur)
) numbered
where rn = 1
order by sr.alias;
```

This gets you one row per `sr.alias`. If you want one row per `sr.alias` + `c.virtual` then change the `partition by` clause accordingly.